# Find the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenspaces of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix is 3x3

```
      [1 0 0                     
       2 1 0    
       3 2 0]
```

I have find out the eigenvalues of this matrix but what would be the corresponding eigenspaces for this matrix?

Comment: @mb14 For any eigenvalue, the definition of an eigenvector gives you a system of equations that you can solve

Comment: @BenGrossmann I want eigenspace. Can you solve this question. It would be a great help.

Comment: @mb14 Do you understand the relationship between eigenvectors and eigenspaces?

Comment: No @BenGrossmann. That is why I am not able to solve it.

Comment: @mb Then that is context that you should include in your question. Please [edit] your post to say what your result was for the eigenvectors and add a note that you do not know how to use this to get the eigenspaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, here is how we would find the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$. Begin by finding the associated eigenvectors by solving the system of equations
$$
(A - \lambda I)x = 0 \implies \pmatrix{0&0&0\\2&0&0\\3&2&-1}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}.
$$
In fact, the eigen**space** of $A$ associated with $\lambda = 1$ is the **solution space** to the above equation, that is, the set of all vectors satisfying $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$.

We find that solution space is one dimensional, which is to say that we only end up with the eigenvector $x = (0,1,2)$. This eigenvector forms a **basis** for the eigenspace.  So, the eigenspace associated with $\lambda = 1$ is the set
$$
E_{1} = \{t \cdot (0,1,2): t \in \Bbb R\} = \{(0,t,2t):t \in \Bbb R\}
$$
(or possibly $t \in \Bbb C$, depending on the context).

Comment: Do you want to say that eigenvector and eigenspaces are same?

Comment: What will be the Eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue=0. I have found out the matrix in reduced row echelon form. Matrix is [1 0 0                                      
                                           0 1 0                                     
                                            0 0 0]. How to proceed further?

Comment: @mb14 It's not clear what you mean when you say that they are "the same". An eigenvector is a vector and an eigenspace is a subspace, so they are different kinds of objects. However, they are related: every eigenvector is an element of the associated eigenspace, and every non-zero element of an eigenspace is an eigenvector.

Comment: @mb14 Any non-zero solution to the equation 
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}
$$
is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $0$. From there, you can use the eigenvector to describe the eigenspace $E_0$ in the exact same way that I used $(0,1,2)$ to describe $E_1$

Comment: Thank you @Ben Grossmann for your explanation.